# Why does this RL circuit gives out wrong results when a square wave generator is applied across it?

Tags: inductor, power-electronics, passive-networks, phase-shift

The circuit below is an RL circuit with a square wave generator created in falstad website.

[http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+14.235633750745258+47+5+50%0Av+176+256+176+80+0+2+50+10+0+0+0.5%0Ar+176+80+336+80+0+180%0Aw+176+256+336+256+0%0Al+336+80+336+256+0+2+0.02086883215129382%0Ao+1+64+0+4099+10+0.05+0+2+1+3%0Ao+3+64+0+4099+20+0.05+1+2+3+3%0A](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2014.235633750745258%2047%205%2050%0Av%20176%20256%20176%2080%200%202%2050%2010%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%2080%20336%2080%200%20180%0Aw%20176%20256%20336%20256%200%0Al%20336%2080%20336%20256%200%202%200.02086883215129382%0Ao%201%2064%200%204099%2010%200.05%200%202%201%203%0Ao%203%2064%200%204099%2020%200.05%201%202%203%203%0A)

I am using a 50Hz, 240V square wave generator , a resistor of 180 Ohms, an inductor with 2H

1) Why the **voltage** across the **resistor** is **sawtooth** shaped ?, it must be a **square wave** since the voltage across a resistor can change instantaneously.

2) I am not surprised to see a square wave shaped voltage across the inductor, but why is it not flat all the way? Why is it **decreasing as the current rises**?

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing are the initial trajectories of exponential waveforms. If you reduce the square wave frequency, you'll get a better picture of what's happening. With the present frequency, the responses do look like triangular waves, but if you look closely you'll see they are in fact curves, not lines.

The time constant of the circuit is \$\frac{1}{LR}= 2.8ms\$, so try square wave frequencies of, say, 1Hz and 10Hz.

Comment: The voltage across the resistor cannot be curve shaped. 
The voltage across the resistor must be a square wave since the voltage across a resistor can change instantaneously.

I even reduced the frequency to 5Hz and still no luck

Comment: The voltage across the resistor is exponential, and given by: \$V(1-e^{-LRt})\$.

Comment: @Amy That explanation makes no sense. The voltage across a resistor *can* change instantaneously, sure, but why does that mean it has to? The voltage across an inductor can also change instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

What you should see is this: -

[image]

If false-tad is showing something different then it's because it's a basic toy and can't be relied upon (a tad-false as per my version of the name). No pro engineer would use it.

Think about it another way. Imagine the starting point was no voltage applied and no current flowing then you instantly applied 10 volts. The equation for an inductor tells you that current change does not happen instantly in an inductor: -

\$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$

The rate of change of current is fixed by the ratio V/L but the actual current starts rising from zero amps hence, all the input voltage appears across the inductors terminals at that instance. As current rises (due to di/dt and time) more voltage appears across the resistor (ohms law) and less across the inductor hence, the inductor voltage dies away from that initial instantaneous peak.

Comment: Why does the voltage across the resistor have a curve shape? 

The voltage across the resistor must be 100% identical to square wave input waveform of the source?

Comment: @amy the resistor voltage MUST BE the input square wave voltage minus the inductor voltage. There is no other option because all three are in series and, at any point in time VL+VR=Vsource hence VR=Vsource-VL.

Comment: Why is it that

When the source generates a 10V, the inductor voltage goes up to 20V and comes back to 0. 

When the source generates a -10V , the inductor voltage goes up to -20V and comes back to 0.

Comment: It doesn't do that in my picture and neither should it. If it does that in falsetad then falsetad is wrong and can't be relied upon. Like I said in my answer, it is a toy and no pro engineer would use it.

Comment: I get it. Its because your square wave from the source goes from 0 to +10 while my square wave goes from +10 to -10

Comment: But, do you understand the sensible answers given?

Comment: It's merely because the frequency in the simulation the asker linked is too big (for this inductor size) to fully charge or discharge during a duty cycle. If I decrease the inductor value, the Falstad simulation matches the diagrams you have drawn here.